# How to Set ActionMainMenuBar Menu Item Colors

Tags: delphi

I can't figure out how to set the color for menu items on a TActionMainMenuBar. Changing the color property of of each TActionClientItem (the "menu items") has no apparent effect. I have been able to change the color of the menu bar itself by connecting the TActionMainMenu bar to a standardcolormap and changing the colormap's color property. I did find [this discussion](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/f8/300232.html) of the issue and it appears that the changes noted in the discussion are reflected in XE7 (my environment) but I am nevertheless unable to change the color of menu items.

Comment: I guess the theme api isn't interested in this. Probably you need an unthemed app or the dreaded VCL styles.

Comment: I wish I could go with an unthemed app or VCL styles, @DavidHeffernan, but my apps heavily use TMS controls so going unthemed would clash with the styling of the TMS controls. I would use the TMS mainmenu component (which would of course harmonize with everything) but my apps have floating windows that need to retain focus when the menu is clicked.And ripping out the TMS controls would be a massive amount of work.

Comment: If you want to be themed then you should respect the theme surely?

Comment: I don't quite follow, @DavidHeffernan.

Comment: One of the goals of themes is to enforce consistency

Comment: I think I have a workaround. One of the VCL styles is similar  to the TMS style that I am using, so enabling the VCL style harmonizes the ActionMainMenuBar (and standard dialogs, too) with the TMS style.

Comment: Using TMS is already a fail :) ...